# Thread local global scope variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, storage-duration

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using std::cout;
using std::thread;

thread_local int a;

void foo()
{
    a = a + 1;
    cout  << a << "\n";
}

void bar()
{
    cout << a << "\n";
}

void baz()
{
    cout << "Something\n";
}

int main()
{
    thread first(foo);
    thread second(bar);
    thread third(baz);
    second.join();
    first.join();
    third.join();
    cout << a;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/772d50f08f5897de)

Since `a` has thread storage duration, we have at least three different objects, denoted by a and used in `first`, `second` and `main` threads. We don't use `a` inside `third`. Is there zero-initialized `a` which can be used in third? I ask this question because I can't find anything about this in the Standard:

> Non-local variables with thread storage duration are initialized as a
>   consequence of thread execution.

Is it implementation defined?

Comment: Your question is about non-observed behavior; it doesn't make sense to say whether a zero-initialized `a` does or does not exist in `third`.

Comment: @ecatmur It is a bit unclear. Does zero-initialized object realy not require memory allocation?

Comment: Not in any observable sense. The implementation may allocate memory, but that isn't visible to the program.

Answer (score 2):

N3337, 3.7.2.2

> A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before
>   its first odr-use (3.2) and, if constructed, shall be destroyed on
>   thread exit.

3.2.2 is too long to copy it here, but essentially, it can´t be "odr-used" if it doesn´t appear in the executed code. So it is not (necessarily) initialized with something.